# Rebinding Data to the Listbox dropdown in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Rebinding the Dropdown `ListBox` with the `Checkbox` ticked for the selected values fro mthe collection of another `DataTable`

```
<div class="t-col t-col-xs-4 t-col-sm-4 t-col-md-4 t-col-lg-4 t-col-xl-4   MinHeight4row">
    <div class="t-col t-col-xs-4 t-col-sm-4 t-col-md-4 t-col-lg-4 t-col-xl-4 padding-0 margin-0">
        <div class="label">
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Ranks"></asp:Label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="t-col t-col-xs-8 t-col-sm-8 t-col-md-8 t-col-lg-8 t-col-xl-8 padding-0 margin-0 ">
        <div class=" padding-right-30 inputwrap">
            <asp:ListBox ID="ddlRanks" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" AutoPostBack="false" ></asp:ListBox>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Code i used to bind is bind the listbox.

```
 ddlRanks.DataSource = dtRanks;
 ddlRanks.DataTextField = "Name";
 ddlRanks.DataValueField = "Code";
 ddlRanks.DataBind();
 ddlRanks.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select", "0"));
```

The items to be checked  the listbox is

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Ranks", typeof(int));
table.Rows.Add(25);
table.Rows.Add(26);
table.Rows.Add(2);
```

From the above table ranks need to be checked true wile reloading the data

i tried the following code ,but it is not working for me.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
 {
     foreach (ListItem item in dtRanks.Items)
     {
            dtRanks.Items.FindByText(dt.Rows[0]["Ranks"].ToString()).Selected = true;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `nested foreach loop` to this :

```
 for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
 {
     foreach (ListItem item in dtRanks.Items)
     {
         if (item.Text.Equals(table.Rows[0]["Ranks"].ToString()))
         {
             item.Selected = true;
         }
     }
 }
```